# Could not initialize class com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory

Tags: 2013

Can you point me in the right direction for resolving this error?  I took the tridion config & jars file from a working project, but the new project gets this error.

> Could not initialize class com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory
>   ============================================================ Some Java classes or interfaces could not be found or loaded
>
> The most typical reasons for this problem are:
>
> - you forgot to configure a classpath
> - a jarfile, zipfile, or directory is missing from your   classpath
> - you have a typo in one of your classpath entries
> - a jarfile required by one of your classes is missing from   your classpath
> - a jarfile on your classpath is out-of-date and does not   contain some new classes
>
> ============================================================
>
> com.tridion.validation.adapter.ContentValidatorSpringAdapter 
>   com.tridion.validation.ValidationFacade 
>   com.tridion.web.jsp.ResponseWrapper 
>   com.tridion.validation.ValidationException 
>   com.tridion.storage.ugc.UGCValidationFacade 
>   com.tridion.ambientdata.web.AmbientDataServletFilter 
>   com.tridion.validation.adapter.ErrorsImp$Error 
>   com.tridion.ugc.validation.DoubleCommentingValidator 
>   com.tridion.validation.adapter.ErrorsImp 
>   com.tridion.web.jsp.JSPXSLTProcessor 
>   com.tridion.ugc.validation.DoubleRatingValidator 
>   com.tridion.web.jsp.JSPProcessor 
>   com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory 
>   com.tridion.webservices.security.authentication.OAuth2AccessTokenHandler
>   com.tridion.validation.ContentValidator  com.tridion.validation.Errors

Comment: it seems related to UGC, is the bundle correctly configured in cd_storage_conf?

Comment: sorry, but I don't know.  Why do those config files work fine for the other site?  I knew I'd need to tweak the settings a bit...

Comment: If it works on another machine, then it should work on this one too, as long as you can access the same storage...

Comment: Is the storage, linking etc licensed and enabled? cd_core logs have more details on the specific error than the web page.

Comment: have you got a cd_wai conf file in your /config directory?  If not put one in there, even it's a stock SDL one.

Comment: I would say double check your configuration files available and triple check your jar files available and compare them with the jars/config available on the server it is working in terms of versions/size etc. In addition, also check your license files and its validity

Comment: Check the contents of your bin and lib directories. If you have the UGC Jars without the right configuration you may see this error.
Also check you have sqljdbc4.jar

Comment: Thanks for all the comments.  I did not have all the correct jars & Tridion DLL's